# Why isn't Roslyn respecting Whitespace trivia, forcing tab indentation instead?

Tags: roslyn

I am developing a little hobby project trying to bring C# down to be compilable to the NES over at [this repository](https://github.com/Machinarius/NINNES). As of commit [9b532f739be](https://github.com/Machinarius/NINNES/commit/9b532f739be2df4d0fe4d99805e92e02878b00a5) some of the unit tests on my first Code Fix Provider are failing only because Roslyn is ignoring the Whitespace trivia that is coming from a node that I want replaced, in [line 90 of the ForbidMuliplicationCodeFixProvider.cs file](https://github.com/Machinarius/NINNES/blob/master/NINNES.RoslynAnalyzers/NINNES.RoslynAnalyzers/ForbidMultiplicationFixProvider.cs#L90). I've also tried NormalizeWhiteSpace on the new node with the same WhiteSpaceTrivia indent size, and a couple other failed attemps, only to always end up with standard tab-size indents on the modified document. Will I have to live with this little bug?

```
  var assignment = SyntaxFactory.AssignmentExpression(SyntaxKind.SimpleAssignmentExpression, variableIdentifier, invocation);
  assignment = assignment.WithTriviaFrom(node);
  var syntaxRoot = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync();
  var modifiedRoot = syntaxRoot.ReplaceNode(node, assignment);

  var modifiedDocument = document.WithSyntaxRoot(modifiedRoot);
  modifiedDocument = await AddUsingStatementAsync(cancelToken, modifiedDocument);

  return modifiedDocument;
```

The `node` variable comes from the original document with 6 spaces (3 tiers of indentation) of WhiteSpaceTrivia, which are supposed to be copied into the replacement node but the output of the modified document has 3 tabs of indentation instead.

My test fails with this message:

```
The checked string has different spaces than expected one. At line 7, col 12, expected '...     test = NESMath....' was '...           test = NE...'.
The checked string:
    ["using NINNES.Platform.Shims;

namespace NINNES.RoslynAnalyzers.Tests.Assets {
  class MultiplicationAssignment {
    public void Multiply() {
      var test = 2;
            test = NESMath.Multiply(test, 42);
    }
  }
}
"]
The expected string:
    ["using NINNES.Platform.Shims;

namespace NINNES.RoslynAnalyzers.Tests.Assets {
  class MultiplicationAssignment {
    public void Multiply() {
      var test = 2;
      test = NESMath.Multiply(test, 42);
    }
  }
}
"]
```

As an aside: Commentary on the Roslyn code would be greatly appreciated, just learning the ropes of the code modification stuff.

Comment: Please show the relevant code instead of links.

Comment: Given how the whole code is required to make sense of the analysis and the fix I posted links, I'll add reduced code samples as soon as I'm able to

Comment: @PoulBak Code added inline.